# Java Muitithreaded CLI

Tags: java, multithreading, command-line-interface

I need to write a multithreaded program in Java which, upon entering some commands does certain tasks in different threads (not really relevant), I need to be able to input the same commands (start, stop and list) whilst the program runs, I've come up with this:

```
public static class RunnableOption implements Runnable {
private int var;

public RunnableOption(int var) {
    this.var = var;
}

public static void start() throws Exception {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

    for (; ; ) {
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(connectionSocket)).start();
    }
}

public void run() {
    switch (var) {
        case 0:
            try {
                start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String option;

    System.out.println("Available commands: start, stop, list");

    while (true) {
        option = read();

        RunnableOption server;

        switch (option) {
            case "start":
                server = new RunnableOption(0);
                Thread t0 = new Thread(server);
                t0.start();
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

}

It does what it's supposed to, but I'm unsure if this is even  a good way to tackle this (imho, it looks really bad), can someone give some insight on this?

Thanks,

EDIT: code has been simplified a bit, but for the question is kind of irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a thread pool.  You don't really want to allow for unbounded threads, if you get a lot of threads(hundreds - thousands), it can cause the system to spend more time managing threads than doing useful work.  Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Thanks! I was actually trying to store some other threads into an ArrayList to try and manage them (still trying to get into Java :v ), but looking at this it seems a much better way of accomplishing what I wanted :)